# What is the syntax to create an anonymous instance of IEnumerable in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a function which takes an argument of IEnumerable. Let's call it:

```
Iter(IEnumerable<string> list)
```

I have a single string that I would like to pass into the function. Is there a way to do it without actually creating some object that implements IEnumerable? It seems like I should be able to use a lambda instead, like :

```
string thing1 = "Frank";
Iter( () => { yield return thing1 };);
```

To reiterate, no pun intended, I was wondering if there was a way to use an anonymous function/lambda so I don't have to create a instance of a container.

Comment: You can also always throw it into any collection that implements IEnumerable (ie `new List(thing1)`)

Comment: you can't create an instance of IEnumerable, it's an interface, it can't be instantiated. but you can create an instance of some type that implements IEnumerable.

Comment: Even if you _could_ use yield in a lambda, some object that implements `IEnumerable<string>` would still be created; it would just be created by the compiler instead of your code.  You might as well just use an array at that point.

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
Iter(new [] {thing1});
```

Since your parameter is `IEnumerable<string>`, you can pass an array or `List<string>`.

Comment: That's probably the closest thing. If I remember correctly, lambda expressions are not allowed to implement iterator methods.

Comment: I knew I could do that. It just seemed like IEnumerable<string> should really be able to be implemented using a lambda. I guess the other way would be to create an anonymous class which implemented the interface.

Answer (score 0):

For one string there is also another way:

```
Iter(Enumerable.Repeat<string>("thing1", 1);
```